# Probability question that looks like Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I am working on a probability question that looks like it has the form of a Bayes theorem (false/positive) however I cannot seem to wrap my head around it

Police have DNA from a criminal that committed a crime. The crime was committed by 1 resident of a population of $100000$. They check the DNA sample against a small random sample of the population. The test only gives a false positive $1$ in $50000$ times. The DNA matches MR.X from the database.
What is the probability MR.X committed the crime?

Obviously the probability anyone committed the crime in the area is 
$$\frac{1}{100000}$$

Is the latter information in the question irrelevant here? Or is there something I am missing on how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, one can say there should be about $2$ false positives among $100\,000$ people, plus one guilty person, so three positives, and one of the three is the culprit.

But more precisely, the expected number of false positives should be $\dfrac 1 {50\,000} \times 99\,999$ rather than $\dfrac 1 {50\,000} \times 100\,000.$ But the difference is of no practical importance.

More precisely:
\begin{align}
& \frac{\Pr(\text{Mr. X is guilty}\mid \text{match})}{\Pr(\text{Mr. X is not guilty}\mid\text{match})} \\[13pt]
= {} & \frac{\Pr(\text{Mr. X is guilty})}{\Pr(\text{Mr. X is not guilty})} \times \frac{\Pr(\text{match}\mid \text{Mr. X is guilty})}{\Pr(\text{match}\mid\text{Mr. X is not guilty})} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac{1/100\,000}{99\,999/100\,000} \times \frac 1 {1/50\,000} = \frac{50\,000}{99\,999} \approx \frac{50\,000}{100\,000} = \frac 1 2.
\end{align}

Then, since
\begin{align}
& \frac{\Pr(\text{Mr. X is guilty}\mid \text{match})}{\Pr(\text{Mr. X is not guilty}\mid\text{match})} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac{\Pr(\text{Mr. X is guilty}\mid \text{match})}{1 - \Pr(\text{Mr. X is guilty}\mid\text{match})} \approx \frac 1 2,
\end{align}
we conclude that
$$
\Pr(\text{Mr. X is guilty}\mid \text{match}) \approx \frac 1 3.
$$

Comment: Just to further understand the solution given. The probabilities $\frac{\Pr(\text{match}\mid \text{Mr. X is guilty})}{\Pr(\text{match}\mid\text{Mr. X is not guilty})}$ are independent correct? So we can write $\frac{49999/50000}{1/50000}$ which is what you have given.

Comment: @Yipz There is no need to further understand the solution: it is wrong.  Bayes' Rule is $$\dfrac{\Pr(\text{Guilty and Match})}{\Pr(\text{Guilty and Match})+\Pr(\text{Not Guilty and Match})}$$

Comment: @yipz : Probabilities are never independent; rather _events_ or _random variables_ are independent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp : What do you consider to be wrong here? I applied the identity $$ \frac{\Pr(H\mid D)}{\Pr(\text{not H}\mid D)} = \frac{\Pr(H)}{\Pr(\text{not } H)} \times \frac{\Pr(D\mid H)}{\Pr(D\mid \text{not }H)}. $$ This is equivalent to what you stated, except that you omitted to say $\Pr(\text{guilty} \mid \text{match}) = \cdots. \qquad$

Comment: @GrahamKemp  Or to put it more bluntly: You are wrong. $\qquad$

Comment: @yipz : Please note that Graham Kemp's assertion that this answer is wrong is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be the event of Mr X being guilty, and $M$ the event of a DNA match.   You are thereby told the probability that Mr X was the one who committed the crime: $\mathsf P(G)=1/100000$ and the probability for a *false* positive match: $\mathsf P(M\mid G^\complement)=1/50000$.

You are not told the probability for a *true* positive match, but assume it is close enough to certainty; that : $\mathsf P(M\mid G)=1$ .

You are asked to find the probability of guilt given a match: $\mathsf P(G\mid M)$.  Use Bayes' Rule and the Law of Total Probability:

> $$\mathsf P(G\mid M)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(M\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)}{\mathsf P(M\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)+\mathsf P(M\mid G^\complement)~\mathsf P(G)}$$

Comment: should
 $$\mathsf P(G\mid M)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(M\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)}{\mathsf P(M\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)+\mathsf P(M\mid G^\complement)~\mathsf P(G)}$$
not be 
 $$\mathsf P(G\mid M)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(M\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)}{\mathsf P(M\mid G)~\mathsf P(G)+\mathsf P(M\mid G^\complement)~\mathsf P(G^\compliment)}$$

Comment: @yipz : Note that "compliment" and "complement" are two different words. The latter is the one that is appropriate here.